# Combining jQuery document.ready functions

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I've got an old and messy site and am trying to start tidying up some of the jQuery code to make it easier to maintain and want to get all my document.ready functions into a single call. The problem is that the pages each have a different set of includes some of which have their own .ready function.

What I thought of doing is putting this in the main page:

```
var documentReadyFunction = function() {
    //do something
};
```

And having this in my header/scripts file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof documentReadyFunction != 'undefined') {
        documentReadyFunction();
    }
});
```

Which works fine if I was able to know all the on ready functions needed in one place, but what I want to be able to do is to add more scripts to be run in the .ready from the files between the two calls - any suggestions on how I can achieve this or if its a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way;

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function(){
    init();
 });

 function init(){
   someFunction();
   //other init stuff
 }

 function someFunction(){
   }
</script>
```

(Or) If you want to have multiple document.ready you can do this way:

From here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // some code here
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  // other code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're aware of this, but I'm pretty sure multiple calls to $(document).ready(fn) are permitted and they don't override the original function, but also call it.

See http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready for more information. Note that if one of them has an error, the following functions will not execute.

Comment: I realise you can do multiple .ready calls but there are some functions that need to be run in a certain order (eg. Lazy loading of images and applying jcarousel require running in a certain way to both be applied to the same group of images). I was hoping to be able to declare them where they are used and then loading them up in the right order (as opposed to having to juggle the page around so their .ready() appears the right way around.) - I had wondered about somehow creating an array of functions that I would always push one function on the start and the other on the end.